# Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies when working with work with Azure data factory and logic app

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to trigger logic app workflow via ADF pipeline. I have provided the URL from logic app in the ADF web activity but still its throwing an error message like:
**GetSpnAuthenticationToken: Failed while processing request for access token with error: Failed to get access token by using service principal. Error: invalid_grant, Error Message: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.**

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can get more information about the failure from within your Azure portal.

- Go to the `Sign-in events` page.
- Click on `User sign-ins (non-interactive)`.
- Look for your event with Status = Failure.
- Click on the failure event and a side bar detail will pop out.
- Click the `Conditional Access` tab within that detail pop out.

Here you will see the policy that caused the block. Now you can review that policy!

You may find that your application is breaking a rule that shouldn't be modified. Consider changing the way your application works rather than bending security rules to your whim.

Looks like this:

[image: Conditional Access]

Answer (score 1):

Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies when working with work with Azure data factory and logic app

> **GetSpnAuthenticationToken: Failed while processing the request for access token with error: Failed to get access token by using service principal. Error: invalid_grant, Error Message: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.**

The above error is because of the conditional Access Policy being enabled by your Global administrator in Azure Active Directory that is preventing access to the Logic App to retrieve access tokens from Azure Data Factory (ADF).

**To resolve the issue:**

***The conditional access policies in Azure Active Directory must be reviewed and modified in order to permit token issuance for the service principal used by Azure Data Factory.***

- Login with an account with the necessary rights to administer Conditional Access rules. (Global Administrator)
- Navigate to Azure Active Directory (AAD) >> Security >> Conditional Access.
- Examine the current Conditional Access policies to find any that could be preventing token issuance for the Azure Data Factory service principal.
- Change that policy or make a new one that allows the service principal to issue tokens. You can exclude the service principal from the conditional access policies it is being applied upon.
- Save the Conditional Access policy changes and retry.

**Refer to below docs for more information about the conditional access policy:**

- [azure-docs/articles/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-block-access.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-block-access.md)
- https://www.argos-security.io/2021/11/29/how-to-secure-an-azure-service-principal-with-conditional-access/